# Unable to install skype form .Deb File

Tags: software-installation

When I install Skype from  a .deb source in my ubuntu 14.04 64bit, the following error occurs `This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources`. 
Details `"libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386`" .

Answer (score 1):

You can Download Skype from other source.

1) From Terminal :-

- `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install skype`

2) Ubuntu software center , Just search '**Skype**' on Search Box

Comment: sudo apt-get install skype doesnot install skype through terminal..

Comment: What release are you using?  It shows up in standard repos here.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following website:
http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/

Select the version of ubuntu you are using or select the latest previous version e.g. as you are using 14.04, select 12.04. When the pop up appears for downloading make sure "Open with Ubuntu Software Center" is selected. Then when downloading is finished you will be able to install it.

You can also install direct from Ubuntu Software Center by searching Skype and then clicking on the installing button from there.

Good Luck. If you still face problem don't hesitate to ask.